# jquery to get each and every row of table and rename its name attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very new to jquery. I have a html table which contains multiple rows and each row have number of cells. Now I want to rename the *'name'* attribute of controls in each and every cell on delete operation of a row.
Here is my html:

```
<table id="workDescTable" class="table invoice-table">
    <tr>
        <th>Item</th><th>Description</th><th>Cost</th><th>Quantity</th><th>Taxable</th><th>Line Total</th><th></th>
    </tr>
<tbody id="NewWorkDesc">
    <tr>
        <td style="min-width: 200px">
            <div class="form-group" style="min-width: 100%">
                <textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="Invoice.WorkDesc[0].WorkItemName" style="min-width: inherit"></textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="min-width: 300px">
            <div class="form-group" style="min-width: 100%">
                <textarea class="form-control text-box multi-line" name="Invoice.WorkDesc[0].WorkDescription" style="min-width: inherit"></textarea>
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="max-width: 100px">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Amount0" alt="0" name="Invoice.WorkDesc[0].Amount" type="number" value="0">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="max-width: 75px">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="qty0" alt="0" name="Invoice.WorkDesc[0].Quantity" type="number" value="1">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td style="max-width: 10px">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control text-danger" id="taxable0" alt="0" name="Invoice.WorkDesc[0].Taxable" type="checkbox" value="true">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="lineTotal0" alt="0" name="Invoice.WorkDesc[0].LineTotal" type="number" value="0">
            </div>
        </td>
        <td><a id="deleteWorkDesc" value="" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash" style="color:red"></a>

        </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is my jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').on('click', '#deleteWorkDesc', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        var tableRows = $('#NewWorkDesc tr');
        $.each(tableRows, function (i, val) {

            //here i want to loop the rows and rename the name attribute of controls in each cell. 
            // for ex I want to change the  name="Invoice.WorkDesc[3].Taxable" to name="Invoice.WorkDesc[1].Taxable"  just changing index values
        });
    });
});
```

Also here is a fiddle: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bajfgxqz/6/)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bajfgxqz/6/ - please see Tushar

Comment: You should include everything necessary to recreate your problem *within the question*, the fiddle is only an extra to allow us to actually "fiddle".

Comment: I actually have an html table where the controls in each cell have name attribute. The name attribute of each control will contain a index value within its name. My problem is when I delete any table row in between then I need to loop the table to set the index values from zero again. my fiddle have the html as well as javascript. I only don't know how to get each cells name attribute during looping and set my desired index value. I tried but no success!

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I only meant you should include your HTML here, not rely on it being in the fiddle

Comment: I noticed you're reusing IDs in your HTML (deleteWorkDesc), you can't do that. If you need to use it more than once make it a class.

Comment: Talya, Thanks. I understand you. I will consider your suggestion and update my issue accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the selectors a bit and the replace the `[2]` stuff by the actual index.
Here you are:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table').on('click', '#deleteWorkDesc', function () {
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        var tableRows = $('#NewWorkDesc tr');
        $('#workDescTable tr').each(function (i, val) {

            $(this).find("input, textarea").each( function (n, nval) {
            //here i want to loop the rows and rename the name attribute of controls in each cell. 
            // for ex I want to change the  name="Invoice.WorkDesc[3].Taxable" to name="Invoice.WorkDesc[1].Taxable"  just changing index values
                $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name').replace(/\[\d+\]/, "[" + (i+1) + "]") );
                console.log($(this).attr('name'));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bajfgxqz/7/

it spits out:

```
Invoice.WorkDesc[2].WorkItemName
Invoice.WorkDesc[2].WorkDescription
Invoice.WorkDesc[2].Amount
Invoice.WorkDesc[2].Quantity
Invoice.WorkDesc[2].Taxable
Invoice.WorkDesc[2].LineTotal
Invoice.WorkDesc[3].WorkItemName
Invoice.WorkDesc[3].WorkDescription
Invoice.WorkDesc[3].Amount
Invoice.WorkDesc[3].Quantity
Invoice.WorkDesc[3].Taxable
Invoice.WorkDesc[3].LineTotal
...
```

Comment: Mr.Axel. This is exactly what I wanted and its also kind of learning for me. Thanks much :)

Comment: @Axel Thanks for the regex, just what I needed today. +1